# pouchdb put is still rejected with _rev

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I'm using pouchDB for the first time, and as indicated in the docs I'm using put() so it will automatically handle revisions. However, when the code is running and there's an existing item with the same ID, it's still rejecting even when including a _rev.

Here's my code:

```
var db = new PouchDB('blog')
...
function saveCategory(category) {
  var savedCategory = {
    _id: 'category' + category.id,
    _rev: '2-' + String(new Date().toISOString()),
    name: category.name,
    nicename: category.slug,
    post_count: category.count,
    description: category.description,
    link: category.link,
    parent: category.parent
  }   

  return db.put(savedCategory).then((response) => {
    $log.log(response)
  }).catch((error) => {
      $log.error('error saving category ',error)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the purpose of the `_rev` field. It is always generated by the server and not by your code. To update a document you must pull the entire document (including the `_rev` field), update the desired fields, and then put the document. The value of `_rev` should be the same as when you got it from the server.

If you have a new record, you do not need to set `_rev`.

[The pocketDB guide has a very useful section about this](https://pouchdb.com/guides/documents.html#understanding-revisions-rev).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to handle this automatically? Given the use case of first instance the user refreshing data -- not having to check existing data?

Or simply, if a refresh takes place, should I just delete all existing records and start over?

Thanks!!

Comment: @ChrisPawlukiewicz If it's a new record, don't include `_rev`. If you're updating a record, you have to first retrieve the record, then don't change `_rev`. In short, don't do anything and let pouchdb do its job.